# Is it OK to use reference to the object owned by a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, c++14, shared-ptr

I found this is working well but don't know if this is safe as I don't understand why it works:

```
struct X{
  static X& make(){
    return *std::make_shared<X>();
  }
  ...
}

int main(){
   const auto& a = X::make();
   a.function();
   ...
   // seems like the instance holds and nothing broken
}
```

In my understanding, the returned reference to the derefed object out of `shared_ptr` `operator*` should not impact how `shared_ptr` manages the instance's reference count: so the created instance inside `make()` should be destroyed after `make()` is done. But this pattern of code has been working well for many times and I don't see why. So I'm not sure if we can really do it in this way... appreciate any comments!

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: *"But this pattern of code has been working well for many times and I don't see why."* - luck. Perhaps the memory you are referencing just happens to still contain the same data but it could be overwritten at any time.

Comment: Why not return the shared pointer?

Comment: Thanks Martin for asking, I was working on DSL API to chain a few ops in one statement, for example: –

    auto query = table("name").select(...).groupby(...).sortby(...).limit(10);

I would like to avoid -> between these function calls, so I have choice to return object itself for table(), but the object may be destroyed soon after method chain, if I allow object copy for every call in the chain, I guess it should work. So I was looking ways if I can keep object ref type for every function but still keep the object, then I found above pattern working, and was looking for opinions on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the shared pointer returned from `make_shared` is instantly destroyed after the return and thus the reference obtained by dereferencing it will be dangling. It might *look* like it works but it really is just undefined behavior, and as said in the comments undefined is undefined.

Comment: Indeed.  An in case someone is not convinced, here the demo: https://ideone.com/e2tspU